# If $X=\{1,2,3\}$, is $\tau=\{\phi,\{0\},\{1,2\},X\}$ a topology on X?

Tags: general-topology

I have been told that if

$$X=\{1,2,3\}$$ and $$\tau=\{\phi,\{0\},\{1,2\},X\}$$ then $\tau$ is a topology on X. But I am not sure why.

The first axiom is held, $\phi$ and $X$ are in $\tau$.

Now I check if the intersection of any two sets in $\tau$ is again in $\tau$.

So lets say I look at the sets $\{0\}$ and $\{1,2\}$. The union of these two sets is $\{0,1,2\}$ which is not in $\tau$ hence this is not a topology.

Is this right?

Comment: Beware, $\tau$ is not a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$...

Comment: $0\notin X$ so $\{0\}$ is not a subset of $X$ hence cannot be an element of $\tau$. I suspect it must be interchanged with $\{1\}$.

Comment: As it is written, the set $\tau$ is not a topology by definition; perhaps the author intends to write $\{ 3 \}$ instead of $\{ 0 \}$.

Comment: I think there may be a mistake in the notes.

Answer (score 1):

What might have ben meant: if $X = \{1,2,3\}$ then $\tau = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{1,2\},X\}$ is a topology.

Then the sets in the topology actually form a finite chain, as $\emptyset \subset \{1\} \subset \{1,2\} \subset X$, and then it's quite easy to show (in general) that this is a topology. The intersection is the minimum, the union the maximum.